# Service account object must contain a string "private_key" property. (property is present)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm trying to spin up a nextjs / firebase template with authentication out of the box.

I'm base64 encoding my private key, decoding it, and loading into the init function in `initAuth.js`.

I'm logging the decoded json into the console and the private key property clearly exists. But I'm getting this error that the value is missing.

`initAuth.js`

```
const privateKeyBase64 = process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY;
let buffer, privateKey;
if (privateKeyBase64) {
  buffer = Buffer.from(privateKeyBase64, "base64");
  privateKey = buffer.toString("utf-8");
  console.log(privateKey);
}

init({
  // ...
  privateKey: privateKey ? JSON.parse(privateKey) : undefined,
});
```

The `console.log()` output looks like this (with sensitive stuff removed).

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- STUFF \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

This is the error I get:

> FirebaseAppError: Service account object must contain a string "private_key" property.
> at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseEr-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28) at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28) at new FirebaseAppError (/home/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:125:28) at new ServiceAccount (/home/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:134:19) at new ServiceAccountCredential (/home/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:68:15) aror [as constructor] (/home/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
> at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
> at new FirebaseAppError (/home/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:125:28)
> at new ServiceAccount (/home/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:134:19)
> at new ServiceAccountCredential (/home/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:68:15)
> at Object.exports.cert (/home/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential.js:34:54)
> at z (/home/node_modules/next-firebase-auth/build/index.node.js:2:16085)
> at /home/node_modules/next-firebase-auth/build/index.node.js:2:16932
> at Generator.next ()
> at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/me/project/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24) {
> errorInfo: {
> code: 'app/invalid-credential',
> message: 'Service account object must contain a string "private_key" property.'
> },
> codePrefix: 'app'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed to provide the `privateKey` property of the PEM json, rather than the entire json object.